# How to have condition inside a string generation line of code in Python

Tags: python, string, conditional-statements

I am trying to achieve this:

```
myString = "%s" % ("banana" if myDict['fruit'] not 'None' else: "NOT a banana")
```

I would like to keep this optimised and do the logic while generating the string. What would be the correct syntax to perform a logic inside a string generator.

Edit:

So the above example was constructed in a bit of a hurry, here is something that hopefully should improve the question, and also this is working just fine:

```
newValue = "%s %s %s" % ("apple","cherry",("NOT a fruit" if fruit[someKey]=='None' else fruit[someKey]))
```

Comment: `is not None`, not `not None`. Also, that isn't a generator, just a ternary operator ("inline if")

Comment: Did you mean `None` or `'None'` 'cause `None` would make more sense, which means that `myDict['fruit'] or "Not a banana"` is easier. (or `myDict['fruit'] and 'banana' or 'Not a banana'` if you prefer)

Comment: And, on top of all the previous comments, `myDict.get('fruit')`.

Comment: Apologies for the sloppy example. The bit that I added to the end of the question works. Thanks for the help and thanks to @61612 for pointing the syntax issue.

Comment: And about the `'None'` and `None` bit, the value is coming from a YAML dictionary so I was a bit confused: `{'fruit': 'None'}` so `'None'` works. `None` does not work. Despite it is defined as simply `None` in the YAML file. I think it has something to do with how YAML stores `None`. Thanks @Ben

Answer (score 0):

```
if myDict['fruit']:
    myString = 'banana'
else:
    myString = 'NOT a banana'
```

Comment: The meaningful description of the code is also missing.

Comment: @VivekSable Yes, you are right, tried to fix that bit.

Comment: @61612 Apologies, that was a bit rushed, tried to improve the question. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a little vague, so I'll address two possible interpretations of your question.

If you're trying to check whether `"fruit"` is in the dict, the following will do it:

```
myString = "banana" if "fruit" in mydict else "NOT a banana"
```

If `"fruit"` can be present in `mydict` but set to `None`, the code would need to be slightly different:

```
myString = "banana" if mydict.get("fruit") is not None else "NOT a banana"
```

Comment: It is the second case, I was trying to check a value in a dictionary key on the fly, as I was building the string.